# Source model issue from system xml in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, system.xml, source-model

I've created two dropdowns field in the `system.xml` , both of them have the same options, except that one has an extra option: `None`. 
This is the xml:

```
        <field id="printing_option" translate="label" type="select" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0" sortOrder="4">
            <label>Printing option</label>
            <source_model>Vendor\Module\Model\Config\Source\PrintingOption</source_model>
        </field>
        <field id="printing_option_2" translate="label" type="select" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0" sortOrder="4">
            <label>Printing option 2</label>
            <source_model>Vendor\Module\Model\Config\Source\PrintingOption</source_model>
        </field>
```

and in my `Vendor\Module\Model\Config\Source\PrintingOption` I have:

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Model\Config\Source;
use Magento\Framework\Data\OptionSourceInterface;

class PrintingOption implements OptionSourceInterface
{
    /**
     * Printing options: automatic or manual
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function toOptionArray() : array
    {
        return [
            // I want to add the none option for my second field
            ['value' => 2, 'label' => __('NONE')], 
            ['value' => 1, 'label' => __('Automatic')],
            ['value' => 0, 'label' => __('Manual')]
        ];
    }
}
```

I want to add the **NONE** option only for my second dropdown. Is there a way to do this, instead of creating a new source model ? and to avoid duplicate codes ?

Thnx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to do this below way :

**system.xml** file :

```
<field id="printing_option" translate="label" type="select" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0" sortOrder="4">
            <label>Printing option</label>
            <source_model>Vendor\Module\Model\Config\Source\PrintingOption</source_model>
        </field>
        <field id="printing_option_2" translate="label" type="select" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0" sortOrder="4">
            <label>Printing option 2</label>
            <source_model>Vendor\Module\Model\Config\Source\PrintingOption::toOptionsArrayFunction2</source_model>
        </field>
```

> **Vendor\Module\Model\Config\Source\PrintingOption.php**

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Model\Config\Source;

class PrintingOption implements \Magento\Framework\Option\ArrayInterface
{

    /**
     * Return array of options as value-label pairs
     *
     * @return array Format: array(array('value' => '<value>', 'label' => '<label>'), ...)
     */
    public function toOptionArray()
    {
        return [
            [
                'value' => 'labels',
                'label' => 'Labels',
            ],
            [
                'value' => 'dropdown',
                'label' => 'Drop Down',
            ],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Get options in "key-value" format
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function toOptionsArrayFunction2()
    {
        return [
            [
                'value' => 'labels',
                'label' => 'Labels',
            ],
            [
                'value' => 'dropdown',
                'label' => 'Drop Down',
            ],
            [
                'value' => 'image',
                'label' => 'Image',
            ],
        ];
    }
}
```

> **EXPLANATION**

Its working because when Magento tries to load resource model and get its data array, it first checks if there are any methods defined for the source model. If you define a method after your source model with `::` sign, it will only call that method to get options.

Check **/vendor/magento/module-config/Model/Config/Structure/Element/Field.php::_getOptionsFromSourceModel($sourceModel)** function.

But, here it's working. You need to atleast one time use **toOptionArray()** function in your source model file.

Comment: Thnx,it works. Didn't know that we can use the `::` for calling methods :)

Comment: Yeah. We can use same as like default.xml mentioned in this link : https://www.rohanhapani.com/magento-2-get-config-value-in-layout-xml/

Comment: Happy coding, Happy to help !!

Comment: Nope bro @JaiminSutariya . If you don't use toOptionArray() in source file. Then, it will return error. Because, we implements \Magento\Framework\Option\ArrayInterface interface.

Comment: Ohh Yes, you are right.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>I think it will not be possible to achieve your requirements without separate `source_model`.</strike>

But there is another alternative to add dropdown options in configuration field, without using `source_model`. If your options are static and not going to change frequently, you can directly use `<options>` tag in your **system.xml** file.

```
<field id="printing_option" translate="label" type="select" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0" sortOrder="4">
    <label>Printing option</label>
    <options>
        <option label="Automatic">1</option>
        <option label="Manual">0</option>
    </options>
</field>
<field id="printing_option_2" translate="label" type="select" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0" sortOrder="4">
    <label>Printing option 2</label>
    <options>
        <option label="NONE">2</option>
        <option label="Automatic">1</option>
        <option label="Manual">0</option>
    </options>
</field>
```

Comment: sorry, but my fields are not static ones :) In my example are static, just to give you an idea. In reality I am using a collection to populate the dropdown options. Srry for missing this detail

Comment: Okay, No Problem. Then I think, Rohan's answer should work for you.